# Limit problem. Probability picking an item once out of M picks where p(pick) = 1/M+k.

Tags: probability, limits

What is the probability of picking an item one or more times if $p(pick) = \frac{1}{M} + \epsilon$ and we pick $M$ times?

$$p(pick~one~or~more) = 1-p(not~pick)^M = 1 - (1-(\frac{1}{M}+\epsilon))^M$$

I am interested in what happens when M goes to infinity.

$$\lim_{M \to \infty} (1-1/M-\epsilon)^M$$

If $\epsilon = 0$ then we can solve $$e^{\lim_{M \to \infty} M log(1-\frac{1}{M}) }$$

Which after subsitution $t = \frac{1}{M}$ can be handled with L'Hôptial's rule. But if that is not the case I have no idea. Computer caluclations for different $\epsilon$ show that $p(not~pick)^M$ goes to $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\epsilon>0$ then $\left(1-\frac1M-\epsilon\right)^M < (1-\epsilon)^M\to 0$.
And if $\epsilon=0$, $\lim \left(1-\frac1M\right)^M=\frac1e$ should be more or less well-known (and is close to some often used definition of $e$ in the first place).